# How can I see the stack trace in Octave's debug mode

Tags: debugging, stack-trace, callstack, octave

I have a failure in some inner library function in Octave.  I want to debug the calling function, but I don't know how to do it.

- How can I see the stack trace?
- How can I move between frames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit** - [`dbup()`, `dbdown()`, and `dbstack()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/NEWS-3.2.html) are available in Octave 3.2 and greater. http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Debugging.html#Debugging

**old answer**

I don't know of a way to show the callstack.  Once I'm in debug mode, I use [`dbstep()` and `dbnext()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Debug-Mode.html#Debug-Mode) to step into and over, respectively, the next line, and write the calls. Also, you can see the lines of code nearby with `dbwhere()` and `dbtype()`.  This is definitely one area where MATLAB is ahead of Octave.

Answer (score 1):

To this day, the octave GUI (5.2.0 at least) still does not show the call stack. You can run the octave debugger in VS code though, and see the stack trace there. I have used it and it works great. There are actually two octave debugger plugins available for VS code at present. I found the Silva one to work slightly better, the other one seemed not to close down the debugger process always. Use something like this in the launch.json:

```
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "OctaveDebugger",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "octave debug",
            "octave": "octave-cli",
            "sourceFolder": "${workspaceFolder}:/home/username/src/octave",
            "workingDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "yourprogram('stringarg')"
        }
    ]
```

ie the octave cli debugger executable should be on the unix path as well. Even with the Silva plugin I think there is some mechanism by which the octave-cli doesn't always shut down. If you try to start the debugger in VS code and nothing happens, check processes and kill if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone else gets here, I'm adding the answer.
dbstack prints current stack information
dbup goes one step up the stack
dbdown goes back one step down the stack

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).